# Epson ePos javascript with USB cable

Tags: thermal-printer, epson, epos

Is it possibile to use Usb printer with Epson ePos Javascript SDK? Or is it only for ethernet/wireless model?

I hope to find an utility to convert a usb printer to a network listening printer to recycle all my usb printers.

Comment: Hi Tobia! Did you ever get an answer to this question on maybe another channel than stackoverflow? Have you been able to talk to the usb connected printer with javascript?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not find a solution yet.

Comment: we are going to use a little nodejs script using npm package escpos and ws, offering the printing via websocket from within the browser / website. This nodejs package is working with the usb printer like a charm.

Comment: Is it bi-directional? I need to query the printer status and, for example, I cannot use windows spooler. I had to install a virtual USB-COM service and query the printer by a virtual serial interface...

Comment: It's just printing as far a I can see, and it's using Zadig to access the printer directly via USB at Windows. I tested under Mac OSX so far, and it's just working. Link to node module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/escpos

Answer (score 0):

For Linux, we have a utility called rpd, which connects a locally attached printer and listens on TCP port 9100 for incoming connection.  It makes any printer a networked printer, but it's not (yet?) published as open source.

Comment: HI Marc, this seems promising. is this project available right now. Can you please share the link for the same